# Add a row to a matrix in Julia?

Tags: julia

How can I add a row to a matrix in Julia?

For example,

```
mat = [1 2 3; 3 4 2]
```

and I want to add the row `x = [4 2 1]` at the end. I tried:

```
push!(mat, x)
```

but it gives an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For concatenation of matrix such way you can do so:

```
mat = [mat;x]
```

Or use function vertical concatenation:

```
vcat(mat,x)
```

Read more about these operations in the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/arrays/#indexing-assignment-and-concatenation).

Comment: How can I do this inside a function? That is, a function that takes `mat` as an argument, and it should modify `mat` (because of [this](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/faq/#functions), `mat = [mat;x]` won't propagate outside the function)

Comment: Perhaps returning the new matrix and assigning outside function would be good form, as it would also expose changes instead of hiding them in side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

[Concatenation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-array-concatenation-1) need to create new a array and it’s very inefficiently! because the [vcat](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.vcat) function is used

```
julia> @which [mat;x]
vcat(A::Union{Array{T,1}, ...
```

Multidimensional arrays in Julia are stored in column-major order. A good discussion is [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/silly-question-how-to-add-a-row-to-array/33601/10)