# Add a row to a matrix inside a function (and propagate the changes outside) in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia

This is similar to this question:

[Add a row to a matrix in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727839/add-a-row-to-a-matrix-in-julia)

But now I want to grow the matrix inside a function:

```
function f(mat)
    mat = vcat(mat, [1 2 3])
end
```

Now, outside this function:

```
mat = [2 3 4]
f(mat)
```

But this doesn't work. The changes made to `mat` inside `f` aren't propagated outside, because a new `mat` was created inside `f` (see http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/faq/#functions).

Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays cannot have their size changed. There are [pointer hacks](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/julia-users/B4OUYPFM5L8/VKV_LyQJWT8J) to share data, but these do not modify the size of the original array.

---

Even if it were possible, be aware that because Julia matrices are column major, this operation is very slow, and requires a copy of the array.

In Julia, operations that modify the data passed in (i.e., performing computations *on* data instead of *with* data) are typically marked with `!`. This denotes to the programmer that the collection being processed will be modified. These kinds of operations are typically called "in-place" operations, because although they are harder to use and reason about, they avoid using additional memory, and can usually complete faster.

There is no way to avoid a copy for this operation because of how matrices are stored in memory. So there is not much real benefit to turning this particular operation into an in-place operation. Therefore, I recommend against it.

---

If you *really* need this operation for some reason, you should not use a matrix, but rather a vector of vectors:

```
v = Vector{Float64}[]
push!(v, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

This data structure is slightly slower to access, but **much** faster to add to.

On the other hand, from what it sounds like, you may be interested in a more specialized data structure, such as a [`DataFrame`](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer (and for pointing me to DataFrame)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Fengyang's very comprehensive answer and excellent avoidance of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Just adding my 2¢.

`push!`ing is a fairly expensive operation, since at each push a new location in memory needs to be found to accommodate the new variable of larger size.

If you care about efficiency, then it would be a lot more prudent to preallocate your `mat` and mutate it (i.e. alter its *contents*) inside your function, which *is* permitted, i.e.

```
julia> mat = Array(Int64, (100,3)); # mat[1,:] contains garbage values
julia> f(mat, ind, x) = mat[ind,:] = x;
julia> f(mat, 1, [1 2 3]);          # mat[1,:] now contains [1,2,3]
```

If the reason you prefer the `push!` approach is because you don't want to keep track of the index and pass it manually, then you can automate this process in your function too, by keeping a *mutatable* counter e.g.

```
function f(mat, c, x)
  c[1] = c[1] + 1;
  mat[c[1], :] = x;
end;
```

```
julia> mat = Array(Int64, (100,3)); counter = [0];
julia> f(mat, counter, [1 2 3]);
julia> f(mat, counter, [1 2 3]);
julia> f(mat, counter, [1 2 3]);
julia> mat[1:3,:]
  3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
   1  2  3
   1  2  3
   1  2  3
```

Alternatively, you can even create a *closure*, i.e. a function with *state*, that has an *internal* counter, and forget about keeping an external counter variable, e.g.

```
julia> f = () -> (); # creating an f at 'outer' scope
julia> let c = 1     # creates c at local 'let' scope
         f = (mat, x) -> (mat[c,:] = x; c += 1;) # f reassigned from outer scope
       end;          # f now contains the 'closed' variable c 
julia> mat = Array(Int64, (100,3));
julia> f(mat, [1 2 3]);
julia> f(mat, [2 3 4]);
julia> f(mat, [3 4 5]);
julia> mat[1:3,:]
  3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
   1  2  3
   2  3  4
   3  4  5
```

Comment: The efficiency of push! has been discussed many times. The basic message to take away is that it is very efficient most of the time. (And the other basic message is that you should always profile with your particular use case before making statements like this.)

Comment: hahah, my sincere apologies, I didn't mean to offend it :p  Isn't it true that filling a preallocated array by assignment will always be faster than filling it via `push!` though? I can't imagine how a `push!` operation could ever be implemented to be as fast (let alone faster!).

Comment: It's true that preallocating should never be slower. But push! will usually be *almost* as fast, so in any real calculation where you would actually use push!, you will never even notice the push!

Comment: And using push! just makes it much more readable and understandable in my opinion.

Comment: And of course  many times you don't know how much space will be necessary to pre-allocate.